# пользовательский статус на сайте nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

задача состоит в том чтоб, создать кнопку online. точнее когда любой пользователь/гость на сайте смотри любой пост, нужно чтоб статус автора был online если тот в сети. как я это начал делать, делаю на nodejs

автор вошел на сайт, срабатывает этот код (client):

```
function log() {
    socket.emit('login', $('#user_id').text());
}
```

(server):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('login', function  (nick) {
    users.push(nick); 
    socket.nick=nick;
    idsnicks[nick]=socket.id;
    io.emit('userlist', users);
    io.emit('creatChat', '<button id="createChat" data="'+nick+'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Author online</button>');
});
});
```

обратно на клиенте:

```
socket.on('creatChat', function(btn) {
        console.log(btn);
        $('.online').append(btn);
    });
```

где $('.online') это div с классом online в который должна вставляться кнопка о статусе. этот див заранее создан на всех страницах где нужна кнопка. однако это срабатывает только для самого автора, но не для всех пользователей. как сделать чтоб эта кнопка была доступна всем, когда автор поста в сети??

Comment: в данных, в которых содержится информация о посте, необходимо добавить  соответствующий триггер и управлять им

Comment: если я верно понимаю что тригер это соответствующий div то оон там есть изначально, и кнопка в нем появляется но только для самого автора, для других ее нет, но должна быть для всех

Comment: в данном случае, триггер, это булевское значение true/false

Comment: ттогда можно пример , потому что я что то не пол